# Aggregate data per Bank and per day in KQL

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, kql

I'm in working on project with goal of connecting multiple banks, in Netherlands, into our platform.

For now, every time a user connects to a single bank, we want to send out a metric and show it in Azure dashboard.
We are almost there, except that we want to aggregate the sum per day. This is what we have right now:

[image: connections last 3 days]

For example, looking at ABN AMRO, we have:

1. ABN AMRO had **2081** connections on 25/01/2021
2. ABN AMRO had **2325** connections on 24/01/2021
3. ABN AMRO had **5082** connections on 23/31/2021

But what we want is to sum it like this:

1. ABN AMRO had **2081** + 2325 + 5082 on 25/01/2021 = 9488
2. ABN AMRO had **2325** + 5082 on 24/01/2021 = 7407
3. ABN AMRO had **5082** on 23/31/2021 = 5082

This is the query used so far:

```
customMetrics
| where name == "CustomerGrantedConsent"
| extend BankName = customDimensions.BankName
| summarize Count = count() by tostring(BankName), bin(timestamp, 1d)
| order by timestamp
```

How?

Comment: Won't this work? Just add `| summarize sum(CC) as total_by_bank_time by TT, BB` between last two lines (`| summarize CC = count() by tostring(BankName) as BB, bin(timestamp, 1d) as TT` and `| order by timestamp`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `row_cumsum`

```
customMetrics
| where name == "CustomerGrantedConsent"
| extend BankName = customDimensions.BankName
| summarize Count = count() by tostring(BankName), bin(timestamp, 1d)
| order by timestamp
| serialize
| extend cumsum = row_cumsum(Count, BankName != prev(BankName))
```

It will return the output as your require

1. ABN AMRO had 2081 + 2325 + 5082 on 25/01/2021 = 9488
2. ABN AMRO had 2325 + 5082 on 24/01/2021 = 7407
3. ABN AMRO had 5082 on 23/31/2021 = 5082

You can read about the row_cusmum at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rowcumsumfunction).

Comment: this works but I want the the cusmun by bank

Answer (score 0):

```
let T = datatable(day:datetime  , value:long)
[
   "2021-01-25", 3000,
   "2021-01-24", 2000,
   "2021-01-23", 1000
];
T
| order by day asc 
| serialize cs=row_cumsum(value)
| project  day, cs
```

[image]

Comment: almost there. this answer produces a similar effect than https://stackoverflow.com/a/65883309/4254528 I want to have row_cumsum by bank name, not by all banks