# Aggregate data by properties in KQL

Tags: azure, dashboard, kql, askql

This question is a continuation of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65882398/aggregate-data-per-bank-and-per-day-in-kql?noredirect=1#comment116502941_65882398)
I'm in working on project with goal of connecting multiple banks, in Netherlands, into our platform.

Every time a user connects to a single bank, we want to send out a metric and show it in Azure dashboard. We are already doing it, but we want to extend its functionalities.

```
customMetrics
| where name == "CustomerGrantedConsent" and customDimensions.IsInitialConsent == "True"
| extend BankName = customDimensions.BankName
| summarize Count = count() by tostring(BankName), bin(timestamp, 1d)
| order by BankName asc, timestamp asc
| serialize FirstConsents = row_cumsum(Count, BankName != prev(BankName))
```

With this query, we are able to aggregate the sum of the consents of banks, when they happen. This is the result so far. As you can see, , we want to sum the amount with time.
I mean, if yesterday we had 4 consents, today the total is going to be:
`yesterday_count + today_count`
`4 + today_count`

[image]

Right now, if there are no consents today, we don't show the sum of the previous day and that's the problem.
If yesterday, we had 4 consents for BUNQ, today I want to show at least 4:

1. BUNQ had 4 connections 31-01-2021
2. BUNQ in total will have, at least, 4 connections today..

How can we do this?

Comment: In the future, please provide sample input data in `datatable` format, so that it would be easy to copy and paste it, to help with the query. You can easily do it in Kusto Explorer by selecting a few records in the results pane, right-click on the selection, and select "Copy as datatable() operator". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `make-series` instead of `summarize` in order to have `0`s. Here's how:

```
datatable(Timestamp: datetime, BankName: string) [
    datetime(2021-01-29 08:00:00), "ABN AMRO",
    datetime(2021-01-29 09:00:00), "ABN AMRO",
    datetime(2021-01-28 09:00:00), "Invers",
    datetime(2021-01-28 10:00:00), "Invers",
    datetime(2021-01-28 11:00:00), "Invers",
    datetime(2021-01-29 08:00:00), "Invers",
    datetime(2021-01-29 09:00:00), "Invers",
]
| make-series Count = count() on Timestamp to now() step 1d by tostring(BankName)
| mv-expand Count to typeof(long), Timestamp to typeof(string)
| order by BankName asc, Timestamp asc
| extend FirstConsents = row_cumsum(Count, BankName != prev(BankName))
```

The output will be:

| BankName | Count | Timestamp | FirstConsents |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABN AMRO | 2 | 2021-01-28 11:12:50 | 2 |
| ABN AMRO | 0 | 2021-01-29 11:12:50 | 2 |
| ABN AMRO | 0 | 2021-01-30 11:12:50 | 2 |
| ABN AMRO | 0 | 2021-01-31 11:12:50 | 2 |
| Invers | 3 | 2021-01-27 11:12:50 | 3 |
| Invers | 2 | 2021-01-28 11:12:50 | 5 |
| Invers | 0 | 2021-01-29 11:12:50 | 5 |
| Invers | 0 | 2021-01-30 11:12:50 | 5 |
| Invers | 0 | 2021-01-31 11:12:50 | 5 |

Comment: thats exactly what i want!